# How to get CPU usage from related processes?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

If I run top -p $(pgrep -d',' scrapy) I get information on the scrapy process, but this process probably triggers other python related processes. How can I get information on these processes as well in real time as the top command does? 
Thanks,

Dani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a program or script that will gather the CPU usage of all child processes spawned by scrapy.

If you wanted to script this yourself, you could look at the output of `ps -p {scrapy pid} -L` to get all the threads spawned by the instantiation of scrapy.

Or, you could chain together a couple Linux commands to have a one-liner:

```
ps -C scrapy -o pcpu= | awk '{cpu_usage+=$1} END {print cpu_usage}'
```

ps:

`-C` specifies the command name to output

`-o pcou=` tells `ps` to only display cpu usage

awk:

`{cpu_usage+=$1} END` loops over the response from `ps`

`{print cpu_usage}` will send the sum to STDOUT.

Comment: @DaniValverde Enjoy, if it works, accept the answer so others know what to do.  Happy holidays

Comment: @tristan, wouldn't this solution lose accounting info for processes, which have been triggered (started by scrapy), but have already finished by the time this command is run?